# git reports difference even when none

Tags: git

Git shows I have a modified file:

```
> git status StdAfx.cpp
On branch MyBranch
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/MyBranch'.

Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   StdAfx.cpp

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

When I diff it, it says they are different even when they are not:

```
> git diff StdAfx.cpp
diff --git a/somedir/StdAfx.cpp b/somedir/StdAfx.cpp
index fb0263ae54..92b182f686 100644
--- a/somedir/StdAfx.cpp
+++ b/somedir/StdAfx.cpp
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
-// stdafx.cpp : source file that includes just the standard includes
-// blah.pch will be the pre-compiled header
-// stdafx.obj will contain the pre-compiled type information
-
-#include "stdafx.h"
+// stdafx.cpp : source file that includes just the standard includes
+// blah.pch will be the pre-compiled header
+// stdafx.obj will contain the pre-compiled type information
+
+#include "stdafx.h"
```

No whitespace difference at any rate:

```
> git diff -w StdAfx.cpp
```

Maybe line endings?

```
> mv StdAfx.cpp StdAfx.cpp.save
> git checkout StdAfx.cpp
> diff StdAfx.cpp StdAfx.cpp.save
> git diff -w StdAfx.cpp
> file StdAfx.cpp*
StdAfx.cpp:      C source, ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
StdAfx.cpp.save: C source, ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Nope.

Maybe permissions?

```
> ls -l StdAfx.cpp*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 me me  208 Apr 24 15:01 StdAfx.cpp
-rwxrwxrwx 1 me me  208 Apr 24 15:00 StdAfx.cpp.save
```

Nope.

Still thinks I've made changes though, even though I checked it out above:

```
> git status StdAfx.cpp
On branch MyBranch
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/MyBranch'.

Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   StdAfx.cpp

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Still thinks there are diffs...

```
> git diff StdAfx.cpp
diff --git a/somedir/StdAfx.cpp b/somedir/StdAfx.cpp
index fb0263ae54..92b182f686 100644
--- a/somedir/StdAfx.cpp
+++ b/somedir/StdAfx.cpp
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
-// stdafx.cpp : source file that includes just the standard includes
-// blah.pch will be the pre-compiled header
-// stdafx.obj will contain the pre-compiled type information
-
-#include "stdafx.h"
+// stdafx.cpp : source file that includes just the standard includes
+// blah.pch will be the pre-compiled header
+// stdafx.obj will contain the pre-compiled type information
+
+#include "stdafx.h"
```

Why does git think I've made changes  when I haven't? And how can I fix this? Note the problem above is repeated for many, many files.

Note: I am using WSL on Windows 10.

Comment: Take a hash of `StdAfx.cpp`, stash your changes, then take the hash again.

Comment: Still probably line endings. Depending on settings, git may be trying to convert them upon commit but present them in a different form in your working copy.

Comment: I ran unix2dos on the file, still thinks it is different.

Comment: hash is unchanged.

Comment: Both of those commands indicate no diff, as expected. Nothing indicates a diff except `git diff` and of course `git status`. converting the file, using `dos2unix` doesn't fix it. I have `autocrlf=true` FWIW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by repeated applications of

```
git reset --hard      # be careful! will wipe out real changes!
git add -u
git reset             # to unstage them
git reset --hard      # again
```

Not a very satisfactory answer because I couldn't identify a root cause. Perhaps this is due to line endings, but I work with a similar tool set and settings across multiple projects and only this one is a problem child. Or else some weird file permissions issue with WSL. But those are little better than guesses.

But I post the answer here in case someone else gets stuck like this.

Thanks to @torek for his great answer.

Answer (score 1):

It really is almost certainly line-endings (CRLF vs LF).  I recommend *not* setting `autocrlf=true`; if you must set up Git to mess with line endings, use `.gitattributes` to set things.  I don't have one single Right Way recommendation, because the problem you have here is a bit thorny and [all solutions have perils](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/756102-but-it-is-said-do-not-meddle-in-the-affairs).  You need to know what you're getting into, and choose your own course.

If existing committed files—which you can't see directly; they're stored in a Git-only format—have CRLF line endings, turning off *all* manipulation will make the problem vanish.  Future committed files will continue to have CRLF line endings.  You may or may not want to use this solution.

If existing committed files have LF-only line endings, you probably want to turn *on* certain manipulations.  You may want this anyway, along with a one-time commit to fix all the repository files, but you need to be aware of what this does and how it presents everything in the future.

When you're on a system that uses CRLF line endings, and you tell Git to mess with your line endings, Git *will* mess with your line endings, because you told it to.<sup>1</sup>  Setting `core.autocrlf` tells Git: *Guess what I have in my files, and based on your guesses, mess with line-endings.*  This is good because it's easy, but it's bad because Git does not necessarily guess *correctly*.

Using `.gitattributes`, you can mark particular files as *text* and others as *binary*, and tell Git: *for the text files, mess with my line endings; for the binary ones, do not touch these at all*.  This is much more work, but also much safer: Git stops *guessing* and does what you tell it.  You can also tell it, explicitly, exactly *how* to mess with line endings.

The Git project folks themselves use `.gitattributes`, e.g.:

```
$ head -8 .gitattributes
* whitespace=!indent,trail,space
*.[ch] whitespace=indent,trail,space diff=cpp
*.sh whitespace=indent,trail,space eol=lf
*.perl eol=lf diff=perl
*.pl eof=lf diff=perl
*.pm eol=lf diff=perl
*.py eol=lf diff=python
*.bat eol=crlf
```

which is as close as I will get to a particular recommendation.  Note that `*.bat` (batch files) are the only files with `eol=crlf` here.

---

<sup>1</sup>You can just tell Git *never mess with anything* and it won't.  That's the way I prefer to use it, but I also avoid systems that use CRLF line endings, so that I never face the problem in the first place.

---

#### Why checking doesn't work

You tried to check for this sort of CRLF fiddling:

> ```
> > mv StdAfx.cpp StdAfx.cpp.save
> > git checkout StdAfx.cpp
> > diff StdAfx.cpp StdAfx.cpp.save
> > git diff -w StdAfx.cpp
> ```
>
> [shows nothing]

but this doesn't really help, because one of the programs that puts the CRLF line endings in, thereby (potentially) changing the file, is *`git checkout` itself!*  The two files don't differ here, because if `git checkout` changed them, it changed them the same way each time.

#### Key background information

There are two things Git can do to files, in two different phases.  To understand this correctly, you need to know something about how Git stores files.

You need to know—maybe you do already—that each Git commit stores a full copy of *every* file, as a snapshot, but stores it in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and frozen format.  You can't actually *see* these files: you have to have Git extract them, and then you can inspect the extracted files.  But Git has to *transform* them during extraction.

Of course, if all your files were frozen forever and unreadable as well, Git would be useless.  So Git *does* extract your files, to regular everyday files that you can list out, open in an editor, check for CRLF line endings, and so on.  These useful files form what Git calls your *working tree* or *work-tree*.  But these are *transformed* files.  They're not what's actually in the commit.  In a pretty strong sense, these files are not in the repository at all!  They just exist so that you can get work done.

You also need to know about Git's *index*.  The index, which Git also calls the *staging area*, is an intermediate step in both extracting files, and putting files into new commits.  We'll skip many of the details, but note that the index acts as Git's *proposed next commit* and is initially filled-in by copying the frozen-format files out of the commit you check out.  What's in the index includes:

- the file's name, complete with (forward) slashes, e.g., `path/to/file.ext`;
- the file's mode: `+x` or `-x`, stored as `mode 100755` or `mode 100644`;
  and
- via an indirection through a Git *blob object* that you mostly don't need to know or care about, the file's *content*, still in the compressed and Git-only format.

Unlike the copy in the commit, though, the index copy *isn't* actually frozen, in that you can replace it, or even delete it.  This is what `git add` and `git rm` do: `git add` in particular takes the work-tree copy and transforms it, compressing it into the frozen *format*, ready to go into the next commit.

What this means is that the index initially contains all the files *from* the *current* commit.  You manipulate your work-tree files, copy the results *back into* the index, and then run `git commit`, and Git makes the new frozen commit from the *index* data, not from the work-tree files.

**Note that there are two copying steps:**

- One step is *copy from index to work-tree*.  `git checkout` does this: it fills the index *and* it fills your work-tree from the index.
- The other step is *copy from work-tree to index*.  `git add` does this, for instance.

*Each of these two steps can make changes*.  With `core.autocrlf` set, each *does*.

#### How Git modifies line endings

Git can treat any given file as either *text*, meaning *consists of lines with line endings*, or *binary*, meaning *consists of bytes that must be preserved: hands off! no touching!*  With `core.autocrlf` set, Git will guess whether a file is text or binary by examining some or all of its bytes.  (Note: different vintages of Git have different internal tests here).

Since binary files are merely uncompressed without changing any of their bytes, those files are safe.  Git doesn't modify them during either copy.  So only `text` files are interesting here.

There are literally only two changes that Git can make on its own.  You can define *smudge* and *clean* filters if you want more changes—these operate right in the same space, during the copying—but Git only does two things:

1. On copying from index to work-tree, Git can replace LF-only line endings with CRLF line endings.
2. On copying from work-tree to index, Git can replace CRLF line endings with LF-only line endings.

That's *all* Git can do on its own.  If you set `core.autocrlf`, Git does both.

If you use a `.gitattributes` entry, you gain finer control.  The first part is a file-name pattern; `*` matches every file, or `*.txt` matches files whose name ends with `.txt`.  The rest are the controls.  Note that the `text` in all cases tells Git: *do mess with the file*.  The `eol=` tells Git *how* to mess with the file:

1. `*.txt  text eol=crlf`

   Replace LF-only with CRLF during index -> work-tree, and CRLF with LF-only during work-tree -> index.
2. `*.txt  text eol=lf`

   Preserve the file during index -> work-tree, but turn CRLF to LF during work-tree -> index.

There is an older set of attributes that you can write as, e.g.:

```
*.txt crlf
*.jpg -crlf
*.sh crlf=input
```

These tell Git the same thing as `*.txt text eol=crlf`, `*.jpg -text`, and `*.sh text eol=lf`.  You should only use these if your Git version is too old to understand the `text eol=` directives.  Check your particular installation's `git help attributes` output.

#### Caveats

*All* existing commits are frozen for all time.  If some file(s) in those commits are committed with CRLF line endings, they are that way forever, *in those commits*.

If you choose `eol=crlf` as a setting, *future* commits in which you have changed the file at all, will change *all* the lines to have LF-only line endings *inside the committed copy*—the copy you *can't* see.  That's because when you `git add` your updated file, Git will turn all the CRLF endings to LF-only endings as it replaces the stored file in the index.

*Extracting* either the old (CRLF-ending) or the new (LF-only) commits will produce work-tree files that have CRLF line endings.  Although Git will say that the files changed in the commit that stripped out all the carriage-returns—and they did change—you won't be able to *smell* the change in your work-tree because it won't happen there.

If the committed copy of the file has CRLF line endings, but you don't touch the work-tree copy of the file, Git won't copy the work-tree file back to the index copy—at least, not normally.  So the index copy, which is literally exactly the same as the committed copy—they share an internal Git blob object—will still have the CRLF line endings, *even though your `.gitattributes` says `eol=crlf`, implying that adding the file (copying it back into the index) will strip out the carriage-returns.*

Newer version of Git have `git add --renormalize` to let you re-apply updated `.gitattributes`.

In many versions of Git (though I think this may have been fixed in recent ones), changing the `.gitattributes` file doesn't signal Git to check whether the `eol=` settings might have changed.  There is a simple workaround for this: remove or rename the file, and re-extract it, as you did to try to test for CRLF line endings earlier.

That is, after *changing* the `.gitattributes` copy in your work-tree, you may need to *trick* Git into redoing extractions (by removing or renaming the file, then using `git checkout` or `git restore` to copy from index to work-tree again).  You can similarly trick Git into redoing `git add`, by using `touch` or similar on the file to update its time-stamp, then `git add` the file.  (Without `--renormalize` and/or bug fixes, Git doesn't notice that a new work-tree -> index copy would do something different this time.)

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. I learned a lot. However, I didn't learn how to tell why git thinks my file has changed, nor how to fix it. If I understand you, `git diff` is comparing my work tree copy with its internal (inaccessible) version telling me something has changed but we can't see what has changed.  If I remove `autocrlf` from my config it still sees the same diff. (We do have a .gitattributes file and it declares .cpp files as text, unsurprisingly. ) Many of the spurious changes appeared when it rebuilt by index (because switching from WSL to powershell). Is that relevant?

Comment: The core issue is: I have a file (hundreds of files actually) that git think has changed, but it hasn't changed. How do I tell it there are no changes to this file? I'd prefer not to blow away this clone and start again because there are some real changes I do care about (I know which ones). Plus this will just happen again in a few weeks. I've already recreated my local clone several times. So how do I tell it this file hasn't changed? `git checkout` normally does it, but not this time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "rebuilt by index" (typo for "rebuilt my index"?), and I'm not sure if WSL affects the result of `lstat` system calls, but since the index file cache info is based on `lstat` results, that kind of change could indeed be relevant. Normally running `git reset` would quiet things down but there could be issues with the racily-clean tests (see the "racy git" section of https://git-scm.com/docs/racy-git/en) that defeat this.

Comment: A tool that would be useful here (but which Git lacks) is one that would extract the raw-but-unchanged bytes from any given committed or index file, and optionally compare those bytes to the work-tree file, to tell you what's truly inside the underlying Git blobs. Most of the mechanism exists: `git cat-file -p <blob-hash>` always extracts the raw bytes unchanged, writing them to standard output. Turning that into a useful tool is the remainder of the problem, especially with Windows doing weird things to standard output streams.

Comment: Another option is to simply run `git add` on these supposedly-modified files. That copies the work-tree content into the index, doing the same transformation on them as usual. If the resulting index copy matches the current-commit copy, the file is magically no longer modified: it has no changes staged for commit, and no changes not staged for commit either. You can en-masse add all files Git thinks are changed, using `git add -u`; `git status` will then tell you the *real* status in terms of what is "staged for commit", and `git diff --cached` will show you what's really changed.

Comment: If you dislike the result of this `git add -u`, simply run `git reset` (with no additional arguments) to have Git copy the current-commit copy of each file back into the index copy of each file. That is, `git reset` is the opposite, as it were, of `git add`.

Answer (score 0):

Windows uses CRLF for line endings however git converts (if any) CRLF to LF.
`git diff --ignore-cr-at-eol` should yell a clean diff.

More content can be found [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings)

Comment: Both of those commands indicate no diff, as expected. Nothing indicates a diff except `git diff` and of course `git status`. converting the file, using dos2unix doesn't fix those commands. I have autocrlf=true FWIW.  Anyhow this answer doesn't tell me how to fix this problem. I actually think this is a WSL error.